# Is quantum computing limited to a superposition of only two states?

Tags: quantum-state

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qubit):

> A qubit is a two-state quantum system [...]
>
> There are two possible
> outcomes for the measurement of a qubit — usually $0$ and $1$, like a bit.
> The difference is that whereas the state of a bit is either $0$ or $1$,
> the state of a qubit can also be a superposition of both.

Is it true that quantum computing must be based on qubits, limiting it to only a two-state quantum system? Is it physically possible to build a $n$-state quantum-system (where $n>2$)?

---

<sub>This is 'repost' of a ("legitimate") question was deleted by the OP, [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1465/why-does-quantum-computing-is-limited-to-a-superposition-of-only-two-states). I decided to repost it along with the answer which I started writing.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is quantum computing limited to a superposition of only two
>   states?

In theory, it is not. Keep in mind that a qubit is a quantum analogue of the classical "bit" which has only two states $0$ and $1$. In principle, there is no limit to the dimension of the state space of a quantum system. There could even be an "infinite" dimensional separable Hilbert space (in short, separable means denumerable/countable with a one-one onto mapping to the natural numbers). [For non-separable Hilbert spaces there are some complications involved.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60608/nonseparable-hilbert-space)
In the context of quantum information systems with a state-space dimension greater than $2$ are called "[qudits](https://spectrum.ieee.org/tech-talk/computing/hardware/qudits-the-real-future-of-quantum-computing)".

And yes, there has been ongoing work to make physical implementations of higher dimensional quantum systems, like qutrits (with trapped ions), as mentioned by [@Andrew O](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/users/54/andrew-o), [on their currently deleted answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/1466/26) (only users having the privilege to view deleted posts can see it at present).

Relevant paper: [Qutrit quantum computer with trapped ions - A. B. Klimov, R. Guzmán, J. C. Retamal, and C. Saavedra](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.67.062313)

**Edit:**

- @glS mentions [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1468/is-quantum-computing-limited-to-a-superposition-of-only-two-states?noredirect=1#comment994_1469) that in some cases making higher-dimensional quantum systems can, in fact, be easier, which is an interesting fact I did not know earlier.

> In the context of photonics, for example, it is relatively easy to
>   generate states in high-dimensional Hilbert spaces, for example
>   exploiting the orbital angular momentum of single photons. See for
>   example [1607.05114](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.05114) and the many
>   references therein, or [Fickler
>   2012](https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.2376), in which they experimentally
>   demonstrate entanglement of states living in 600-dimensional Hilbert
>   spaces.

- @glS also mentions in the [following comment](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1468/is-quantum-computing-limited-to-a-superposition-of-only-two-states?noredirect=1#comment999_1469) that

> It is also to be noted that the matter of non-separability is
>   absolutely a non-issue for practical implementation of whatever
>   protocol, and also that [continuous variable quantum computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-variable_quantum_information) is a
>   big subject in quantum computing

Comment: *However, practically producing a quantum system in a superposition of three or more systems is much harder*: this is not true. In the context of photonics for example, it is relatively easy to generate states in high-dimensional Hilbert spaces, for example exploiting the orbital angular momentum of single photons. See for example [1607.05114](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.05114) and the many references therein, or [Fickler 2012](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/338/6107/640.full), in which they experimentally demonstrate entanglement of states living in 600-dimensional Hilbert spaces.

Comment: The [Fickler article](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature22986) describes using "off-the-shelf telecommunications components". Great question BTW.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you assume that your quantum computer will be based on qubits, it can operate with an arbitrarily large number of states (if it has enough qubits): The combination of two qubits allow it to calculate with a total of four states, that of three qubits with eight states, etc.